# If a bachelor degree was revoked for a exam misconduct committed within a module, how can that degree be re-earned?

Tags: degree

My question is very simple. If someone was found guilty in cheating during a continuous assessment, and the degree was (about to be) revoked, can that person re-earn it by taking that particular module again? Or that person have to retake the entire course?

(I am sorry for not adding proper tags)

Comment: I suspect that will depend very much on the institution, and on the specific terms of the punishment.

Comment: Ask an appropriate person at the institution  - they will know their rules better than strangers on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the rules of the institution. For example my university has general rules, but each faculty has another additional rules and it's all documented in a document called: education and examination regulations (my university is located in Europe). Try to find those rules and regulations and ask around. My advice is to email them and ask if they have a document (pdf) with the general rules and regulations.

Comment: In examination regulation of my institute, no specific rules have been provided about revocation. Only what would the examiner do upon catching a misconduct and what are the punishments given for a specific misconduct. But none is involved with revocation.

Comment: @ramsil In my country there are also laws and regulations from the government, but the best way is to make an appointment with the dean of the faculty to ask how the rules and regulations are about this topic. I'm pretty sure that the dean would know or otherwise know who or where to refer you to.